# Can someone please explain this symbol?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

I'm trying to learn this piece that is called "Waltz in A minor" and I don't know to play that little symbol.

[image]

Comment: May be way off the case here, but that looks very much like the playback position indicator from a bit of software that is playing back the piece on MIDI. Is this a printed score in a book, or a PDF someone has sent you?

Comment: Listen to several recordings and it will show itself - or not.

Comment: _which_ symbol?

Comment: By any chance, do you mean the tiny notes at the start of the more complete measure?

Answer (score 4):

<sub>(I assume you mean the gray triangle with the vertical line; the two smaller notes at the beginning of the bar are [grace notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_note).)</sub>

Googling for sheet music for "Waltz in A minor" yields a couple of results like [this one](https://www.pianotv.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/04-Waltz_in_A_Minor.pdf) from pianotv.net. None of them have such a symbol at the end of the third bar (or anywhere else) so I guess [Steve Mansfield's hunch](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100321/can-someone-please-explain-this-symbol#comment173305_100321) is right: it's just a software artifact, indicating the current position. It might not even be your software if somebody took a screenshot and sent it to you.